# Scraping javascript with 'data-reactid' content using Scrapy and Splash

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, splash-screen

I am using Scrapy + Splash to scrape some financial data from a dynamic website however the website contains some code (dynamic using 'data-reactid') hence I don't know how to extract

Here is my spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class StocksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'stocks'
    allowed_domains = ['gu.qq.com']
    start_urls = ['http://gu.qq.com/hk00700/gp/income/']
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse,
                args={
                   'wait': 0.5,
                     },
              endpoint='render.html',
              )

    def parse(self, response):
        for data in response.css("div.mod-detail write gb_con submodule finance-report"):
                yield{
                'table' : data.css("table.fin-table.tbody.tr.td::text").extract()
                     }
```

I tried to extract the result to csv using below command but nothing was stored into the csv:

```
scrapy crawl stocks -o stocks.csv
```

Here is the log after running this command:

```
root@localhost:~/finance/finance/spiders# scrapy crawl stocks -o stocks.csv
2018-06-09 10:09:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.0 started (bot: finance)
2018-06-09 10:09:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.1.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.4.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.4.0, Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) - [GCC 5.4.0 20160609], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018), cryptography 2.2.2, Platform Linux-4.15.13-x86_64-linode106-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
2018-06-09 10:09:59 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'finance.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'stocks.csv', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['finance.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'finance', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}
2018-06-09 10:09:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2018-06-09 10:09:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-06-09 10:09:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-06-09 10:09:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-06-09 10:09:59 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-06-09 10:10:00 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-06-09 10:10:00 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-06-09 10:10:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://gu.qq.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-06-09 10:10:00 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://localhost:8050/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-06-09 10:10:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://gu.qq.com/hk00700/gp/income/ via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2018-06-09 10:10:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-06-09 10:10:17 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 962,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 184825,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 9, 10, 10, 17, 510745),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'memusage/max': 51392512,
 'memusage/startup': 51392512,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 1,
 'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 9, 10, 10, 0, 4160)}
2018-06-09 10:10:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

And below is the link and the web structure that I want to scrape:

http://gu.qq.com/hk00700/gp/income

[image]

I am quite new to web scraping, could anyone help to explain how should I extract the data?

Comment: Have a look at selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your data, 
http://web.ifzq.gtimg.cn/appstock/hk/HkInfo/getFinReport?type=3&reporttime_type=-1&code=00700&_callback=jQuery112405223614913821484_1528544465322&_=1528544465323

Splash is not required any where just take a look, change the query parameters in the url and you will get json response enjoy it. Remove the splash browser it doesn't useful at all. it will just increase your response time.

Comment: You are really a genius, however, I would like you to teach me how to find that link for the source data, and there are several report per years, i.e., 2016-2013, 2012-2009, 2008-2005, 2004-2004, how do I loop to get the link of the source data?

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation, I'll give you the permanent solution to this. Where you dont need to use splash or anything else and you can get your data 98% for the sites.

Comment: Thank you Yash, I can find the souce links using Chrome->Inspect->Source, but don't know how to write the code in Scrapy Spider to loop those links and extract the data, could you help?

Comment: @NicholasKan https://medium.com/@yashpokar/scrape-any-website-in-the-internet-without-using-splash-or-selenium-68a6c9733369 you can find full reference here